# Bug in validation of postal code, only 3 digits returned

Tags: c++, debugging

I've working on a small lab project that's purpose is to validate postal code in the following format:

```
ldl dld (l = letter, d = digit)
```

So far, I've found it to be relatively straight forward. However, upon compilation, I've found that the postal code output is only `3` characters long (maybe `4` if the space is there).

If anyone can help point out where I went wrong, I would be most appreciative :).

```
/* Lab direction:
   Write a program that prompts the user to enter a Canadian postal code in the formal of ldl dld, where d is a digit and l is a letter.
   Check it's validity.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Inform user of the purpose of program
    cout << "This program will check the validity of your Canadian postal code";
    string pc;

    //Prompt user for postal code info
    cout << "Please enter your postal code";
    cin >> pc;

    //Check is character is an int or a letter and in proper order
    bool validCode = true;

    //Check postal code length
    if (pc.length() > 7) 
        validCode = false;

    //Check for space
    if (pc.length() == 7)
        pc.erase(pc.begin()+3);

    for (int i = 0; i < pc.length(); i++) {
        if ((i%2==0)&&(isdigit(i))){
            validCode = false;
        } else if ((i%2!=0)&&(isalpha(i))) {
            validCode = false;
        } else {

        }
    }
    pc.insert(3, 1, ' ');
    if (validCode) {
        cout << pc << " is a valid postal code";
    } else {
        cout << pc << " is not a valid postal code";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I am really not sure what is so wrong with this question that people are down-voting and voting to close. Its fairly minimal, it reproduces the error, the error is clearly stated... what more do people want?

Answer (score 1):

Change `cin >> pc;` to `std::getline(cin, pc);` (or else, enter the code without spaces). The latter reads the whole line, while the former stops at the first whitespace.